# Making a software for controlling a hardware device network-capable in .Net/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, network-programming

I am responsible for developing the software for a printer-like device, for which I am using C#/.Net and WPF. We now have the necessity for making this software network-capable, so that the device can be remote-controlled over a local network.

The idea I currently have, is to be implement some way of calling the API-functions of our software over the network. This could be done by a client-side DLL, which sends the commands for the API and receives their responses as well as any events, that the device-software issues.

To this date I have only worked a little with socket-based communication using TCP/IP, where I explicitly sent strings over the network and received them on the other side. I did this completely synchronously. However for the new implementation I will need asynchronous calls to the API to query state, issue events, etc. and it seems like it would require considerable effort to implement this using socket-based communication (am I wrong?). I will have to avoid too much custom implementation, since I am under a time-constraint for the implementation.

In my search I came accross the possibility of using SOAP in ASP.Net, which from this [CodeProject post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/94043/SOAP-Web-Services-Create-Once-Consume-Everywhere), seems to be what I am looking for and does not seem to be too complicate to implement. However in my Visual Studio 2015 installation I am unable to find the project-type they are using there, which is a "ASP.Net Web Service".

My question is now:

Given my choice of technologies (.Net), would this be the most effective way for achieving, what I have in mind? Is it still possible to do this in Visual Studio 2015?

**Update:**

As always I found one of the questions afterwards: Here is an explanation of how to create an "ASP.Net Web Service" in Visual Studio 2015, which I have tested to work. Leaves the question, of whether this is the best way to go for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you would have better luck using web api.  Calling a REST based api is a lighter load on the network and is generally easier to set up.  It is also easier to call from non-Microsoft based clients and usually requires less coding to get started.

[Here](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2016/01/20/restful-api-with-aspnet50.html) is a good tutorial on creating a RESTful web api using .Net Core.  If you have a [PluralSight](http://pluralsight.com) subscription, they have a number of tutorials on Web Api.  If you don't have a subscription, it is well worth the money.

Web Api and WCF are two completely different frameworks.  WCF uses SOAP, which is XML based, meaning that the number of bytes needed to send information is much larger than a RESTful service in Web Api.  It is **much** easier to write and deploy a Web Api application and client than it is to write the equivalent in WCF.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you perhaps point me to some relevant information for Web API? I am currently also investigating using WCF to handle the communication, but I suspect that is not what you are refering to or is it?

Comment: Added some resources for Web Api